# How to rewrite in Haskell a main :: IO () to two functions consisting of one main :: IO()

Tags: function, haskell, url-rewriting, let

I want to make this a simpler main function by splitting some stuff. But when I add a new function maakNieuwSpel I get errors

```
 maakNieuwSpel :: Int -> String -> IO ()
 maakNieuwSpel aantal firstName= do let rijTegels = volleRijTegels
                                    let spelers = deSpelers aantal firstName 
                                    w <- spelSpelen rijTegels spelers 0
                                    putStrLn (w ++ "dit is waar ik mee bezig was in functie nieuwSpel")
```

And when I called it in main with

```
    eindstand <- maakNieuwSpel (digitToInt aantalTegenspelers) firstName
```

it gave errors.

ANOTHER thing I tried and want to achieve is to rewrite the let functions in main by putting a where function. 
Something like this was what I thought

```
    eindstand <- spelSpelen rijTegels spelers 0 
            where rijTegels = volleRijTegels
                   spelers = deSpelers (digitToInt aantalTegenspelers) firstName
```

But then it says "  parse error on input ‘=’ Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?"

This is part of my code. I guess it will you give you enough insight of what I am doing.

```
 data Dobbelsteen = Steen Char -- now its values can be specified
                deriving (Show, Eq)  
 data Tegel = Teg Int Int 
          deriving (Show, Eq) 
 data Speler = Spel Tactiek Spelersstapel String
 type Tactiek = ([Dobbelsteen]  -> [Dobbelsteen] -> IO [Dobbelsteen], [Dobbelsteen]  -> Int -> IO Bool)
  type Spelersstapel = [Tegel]



 main :: IO ()  
 main = do putStrLn ("Hoi! Je speelt regenwormen. Wat is je naam?")
           firstName <- getLine  
           putStrLn ("Beste "++ firstName ++ ", je speelt tegen twee computertegenstanders. Ze heten Lap en Top.")
           putStr "Tegen hoeveel computertegenstanders wil u spelen? (Dit spel is voor 2 tot 8 personen) "
           aantalTegenspelers <- getChar
           let rijTegels = volleRijTegels
           let spelers = deSpelers (digitToInt aantalTegenspelers) firstName 
           eindstand <- {-maakNieuwSpel (digitToInt aantalTegenspelers) firstName-} spelSpelen rijTegels spelers 0
           putStrLn ("Het spel is afgelopen. De eindstand is " ++ eindstand)


spelSpelen :: [Tegel]  -> [Speler]  -> Int -> IO String -- de RijTegels, de spelers en degene die gaat spelen (int)
spelSpelen []        spelers spelerNr = do return (show (bepaalEindStand spelers))
spelSpelen rijTegels spelers spelerNr = do let Spel tactiek stapel naam = (spelers !! spelerNr)
                                           putStrLn ("Deze speler is nu aan de beurt: " ++ naam)
                                           score <- beurt tactiek (\x -> elem x (bepaalGeldigeScore spelers naam rijTegels))
                                           let rijTegelsNieuw = pakTegelAlsMogelijk rijTegels score
                                           let rijTegelsTeruggelegdNieuw = legTegelTerug spelers rijTegels score
                                           let spelersAfgepaktNieuw = pakTegelAf spelers score
                                           let spelersNieuw = voegTegelToeAanSpelerVanStapel spelersAfgepaktNieuw score naam rijTegelsTeruggelegdNieuw
                                           putStrLn ("De beurt van speler " ++ naam ++ " is nu afgelopen.")
                                           printStatus rijTegelsNieuw spelersNieuw
                                           spelSpelen rijTegelsNieuw spelersNieuw ( (spelerNr+1) `mod` 3)  


 volleRijTegels :: [Tegel] -- deze functie maakt de rij tegels van 21 tot 36.
 volleRijTegels = zipWith Teg [21..36] (replicate 4 1 ++ replicate 4 2 ++ replicate 4 3 ++ replicate 4 4)

 deSpelers :: Int -> String -> [Speler]
 deSpelers aantalTegenspelers firstName = do [Spel computerTactiek [] firstName, Spel computerTactiek [] "Lap", Spel computerTactiek [] "Top"]
```

Comment: You have a number of indentation errors. Unless there is a reason to indent, code has to be indented by the same amount as the previous line. The second line of a multi-line `do` block has to be indented to match the text *following* the `do` keyword.

Comment: After fixing indentation errors and adding placeholders for all undefined variables, the final code snippet you posted compiles fine. [Here are my changes](https://gist.github.com/luqui/e3cc0f8ac31cf6275415035a429c1720).  An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You've done everything correctly; there's just a small problem with indentation. Try dedenting the last line of `main`, like this:

```
 main :: IO ()  
 main = do
      -- ... stuff ...
      eindstand <- {-maakNieuwSpel (digitToInt aantalTegenspelers) firstName-} spelSpelen rijTegels spelers 0
      putStrLn ("Het spel is afgelopen. De eindstand is " ++ eindstand)
```

See how in my version, `eindstand` and `putStrLn` have the same number of spaces before them? In your version, `putStrLn` has an extra space before it, causing GHC to think that it is a parameter to `spelSpelen`. It should start to work if you remove that extra space.

Comment: Hej thanks for answering, but it is not that. That is just a mistake of copying the code into stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

This Q&A is probably better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Besides basic indentation problems, wanting to split your `main` in multiple parts is a good idea.

Additionally you will want to try and make some of those parts non-`IO`. For example, it should be possible to address *all* game logic without touching any `IO`. If you don't have any `getLine` or `putStrLn` calls in your game logic, it is easier to test, and there are few sources of errors, since input validation can be separated out into its own part.

As for how the game logic might look like without `IO` embedded into it, I can't say, because the game logic is written in, what, Dutch? If you translate this code to English, or resubmit a translated copy of the code to codereview.stackexchange.com, someone may be able to suggest how to do this.

Comment: This is a little beside-the-point, but part of me wonders if it wouldn't be easier to read the code under alpha-renaming to single-character variable names? Something about the fact that the Dutch is just *somewhat* intelligible makes it more difficult to parse.

Comment: @dfeuer: It sounded to me like this code was only broken by copy-pasting it into Stack Overflow, but you're right.